# Passagem de váriaveis para a view no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou encontrando alguns problemas para passar o resultado de uma query presente na model, para a view no CodeIgniter. Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Minha query : `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM crm.usuario limit 50");`

E quero fazer uma listagem com os resultados na view.

Comment: Pelo que você falou acredito que você usa um modelo baseado em MVC. Você está usando alguma framework? Ou você mesmo criou a estrutura?

Comment: Na verdade a estrutra já foi entregue pronta pra mim, eu apenas fui responsabilizado por fazer algumas alterações...

Comment: Como você renderiza as views? Como você chama elas?

Comment: Perdão, não entendi sua pergunta... Como citei antes, entrei nesse ramo de programação a pouco tempo, e meio que diretamente, sem fazer cursos específicos nem nada...

Comment: Ok.... vou tentar melhorar a pergunta, você provavelmente está fazendo essa query exatamente onde acontece as execuções para renderizar a tela para onde você deseja passar essa query né? Poderia complementar o código com o resto da programação que tem depois da sua $query?

Comment: Minha query está dentro desta função presente na model  ---- public function get_online_users() {
  
  $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->limit('50')
                        ->get('usuarios.crm')
                        ->result();
    }

Comment: Cara é difícil ajudar sem saber o resto do escopo... se é usado uma framework ou não... caso use uma.... elas implementam modos diferentes para mandar informação a view...

Comment: A estrutura é do CodeIgniter, que utiliza MVC

Comment: Lembre de colocar as tags da tecnologicas/frameworks na sua pergunta dessa forma fica mais facil para quem vai responder ou pesquisar. :)

Comment: @rray Ok, valeu brother!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para enviar informações do controller para a view no codeigniter pode fazer dessa forma:

Controller.php

```
 $data['usuarios'] = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result();
 $this->load->view('listagem_usuarios', $data); // carrega a view e envia a variável $data
```

Na sua view acesse a lista de usuarios chamando a chave do array `$data`

```
foreach($usuarios as $item){ 
  echo $item['nome'] .'<br>';
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

[CI - Views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

[CI - Active Record Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

[CI - Queries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: Valeu brother! Resolveu!

Answer (score 0):

opa boa noite, e possivel fazer isso? qdo coloca assim da erro não encontra os dados no foreach,
no controler tenho 
 $data['usuarios'] = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result();

$datatab['tabela'] = $this->db->get('tabela')->result();
 $this->load->view('listagem_usuarios', $data, $datatab);

Answer (score -1):

Passe apenas um parâmetro data:

```
$this->load->view('listagem_usuarios', $data);
```

Na sua view:

```
foreach($usuarios as $item){ 
  echo $item['nome'] .'<br>';
}
```

Ou:

```
foreach($tabela as $item){ 
  echo $item['nome'] .'<br>';
}
```